# Multiline regular expression shell script

Tags: regex, shell

I need to replace a hash for a file in manifest. My problem is I don't know the original hash, only the new one.

**mainfest**:

```
[
  {
    "file": "bundle.js",
    "hash": "0a4c61f0cf23ca1fd39c411140941cd5"
  },
  {
    "file": "0fdbe5712e250dac1fa5930395f65a27.jpg",
    "hash": "0fdbe5712e250dac1fa5930395f65a27"
  }
]
```

As you could see, in the manifest (JSON) file name and hash are bundled in an object.

I want to change the hash file for the bundle.js with a new one. I use below shell script with sed and regular expression to replace the hash.

**shell script:**

```
#!/bin/sh
NEW_HASH="$(md5 < ./scripts/bundle.js)"
sed 's/\({"file": "bundle.js","hash": "\).*\("}\)/\1'$NEW_HASH'\2/g' chcp.manifest
```

Only I don't know how to match the multiple lines. Mine regex matches only a single line

```
{"file": "bundle.js","hash": "0a4c61f0cf23ca1fd39c411140941cd5"}
```

and not

```
{
   "file": "bundle.js",
   "hash": "0a4c61f0cf23ca1fd39c411140941cd5"
 }
```

I tried something like:

```
sed 's/\({"file": "bundle.js",\n   "hash": "\).*\("\n   }\)/\1'$NEW_HASH'\2/g' chcp.manifest
```

but \n doesn't seam to work for matching a new line

Comment: Sed is designed to process files line by line. You should really be using a JSON tool, such as `jq`.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to parse a structured format like JSON (or XML, etc) with something like `sed` or `awk` is tricky and never as robust as using a tool actually designed to parse the data with which you're working.

Your task would be relatively trivial using Python or Ruby or Perl or something else with a JSON parser.  For shell scripts, you may want to investigate the [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) command, which is available as a package for most distributions.

Using `jq`, you could use the technique described in [this document](http://engineering.monsanto.com/2015/05/22/jq-change-json/), which would boil down to:

```
NEW_HASH="$(md5 < ./scripts/bundle.js)"
jq 'map(if .file == "bundle.json" 
        then . + {"hash": "'"$NEW_HASH"'"}
        else . 
        end)' chcp.manifest
```

That would generate the new document on *stdout*; you could obviously save that to a file and then rename that to replace the original.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and pointing me to the jq package. Only I'm afraid the hosting compony won't  install such a package. Indeed maybe Python or Ruby is an option I could try. I upvote your answer, but didn't accept it as 'the answer' because I rather use a simple shell script if possible